# update Rx Observable list when virtual dom change

Tags: javascript, dom, rxjs, virtual-dom

i working with virtual-dom in one hand and in the other ReactiveJS(RxJs), so when i update the dom by virtual-dom this doesn't re-create the dom, it only changes properties, so the Rx.Observable associate to this dom, didn't update when the dom becomes higger.
In concrete is a pagination that can be the number of pages to show change, so the Rx.Observable must be associate to new dom link.
Any idea 
Thanks

Comment: At last, i found the solution by the [author](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/bridging_to_events.html), using the parent as the observable and the node which i need to observe into de function observable is added by on and off from jquery.